# Why does a "release" event generate a "push" event as well?

Tags: github, github-actions

I've read the [Github Actions documentation](https://help.github.com/en/actions), and cannot figure out why a GitHub Action workflow is being triggered with a nearly simultaneous `push` *and* `release` event when I publish a new release. In other words, my workflow yaml file starts like this, designating that it should run for both push and release events:

```
name: Release Actions

on:
  push:
    paths:
    - '**.csproj'
    - '**.cs'
    - '**.css'
    - '**.cshtml'
    - '**.dll'
    - '**.js'
    - '**.sln'
    - '**.yml'
  release:
    types: [published, prereleased]
```

And when I publish a new release (tag), I would expect it to execute once. Yet I see two events trigger nearly simultaneously (~5-10 sec apart):

[image]

Now, the `release` event *does* trigger a `push` to my repo, but the only file being updated is my `package.json` file. And the `paths` definition for the `push` event does *not* list **.json as one of the paths, so I wouldn't expect that push event to trigger it.

So what can explain the second event that is happening, the `push`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The push event is not a commit being push to a branch, it's the tag being pushed to `refs/tags/<tag>`. It's intentional that creating a release generates both a `release` and `push` event.

If you don't want the `on: push` workflow to trigger on tags you can add a `branches` filter that will cause tag events to be ignored, as documented [here](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestbranchestags).

```
name: Release Actions

on:
  push:
    paths:
    - '**.csproj'
    - '**.cs'
    - '**.css'
    - '**.cshtml'
    - '**.dll'
    - '**.js'
    - '**.sln'
    - '**.yml'
    branches:
    - '**'
  release:
    types: [published, prereleased]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. At first I was excited because this did solve the issue of two events happening on `release`. However, now none of my code `push` events (pushing new code commits) are triggering the action any more. All I did was add the `tags-ignore` and `- '**'` lines as you showed.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an alternative solution that I tested. It seems to work for code `push` and only triggers `release` (not `push`) when a release is created.